# Multiprocessing Join() deadlock

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kill

I have a process listening for events: `terminate` and `start`. When I receive a start I do:

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=flowGenerator.keepSending,kwargs=(params))
process.daemon = True
process.start()
self.process = process
```

Then when the process receives a `terminate` event I do:

```
if self.process:
    if self.process.is_alive():
        try:
            self.process.terminate()
            self.process.join()
        except OSError:
            pass
self.process = None
```

However, if If I have an `start` and `terminate` events just one right after. The terminate() function gets locked at `self.process.join()`. What is going on ? If I put a `time.sleep(1)` after every start, so I do not let a `terminate` occur then it never hangs, so has to be some problem with killing the process while is still being created.

I have to add that `process.terminate()` Is handled by a SIGNAL HANDLER that basically does `sys.exit(0)`.

**EDIT:**

Here I will add a full example that is equivalent and has the same problem. If you run main() twice it will hand at `join()`, and it has something to do with handling the signal, because If i remove it it works always.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import signal
import sys
import os

class ProcessTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,self.signal_term_handler)
        self.parentPid = os.getpid()

    def signal_term_handler(self,signal,frame):
        if os.getpid() == self.parentPid:
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            sys.exit(0)

    def dummy_function(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)

    def terminate(self):
        if self.process and self.process.is_alive():
            self.process.terminate()
            self.process.join()
        self.process = None     

    def main(self):
        self.terminate()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.dummy_function)
        process.daemon = True
        process.start()
        self.process = process
```

**EDIT2:**

There where two problems here:

1) You can not use sys.exit(0) inside a signal handler. `sys.exit()` raises an exception so if that exception is caught then the process will never finish and p.join() gets blocked.

2) Even more important and harder. If you take a look at the code I call `p.terminate()` and `p.join()` one after the other. `p.terminate()` will send a `SIGTERM` to the child that will call `sys.exit()` or to be more correct `os._exit()` however since the signal handler runs in a thread the  command `p.join()` will be called and if that happens before reaching the `exit` command in the signal handler it will hang forever.

How could I solve problem number 2?

Comment: What is the `flowGenerator.keepSending` code?

Comment: Its pure python code that does not call any thread or process. It just sends traffic using 2 raw sockets.

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: Please convert the code to a [mcve] and fix the formatting.

Comment: @edgarcosta On Python prior to 3.x multiprocessing is just a layer over fork (on Python3.x this is configurable). I'm assuming you are working on posix. Therefore your signal handling code is also copied to the child process. And since `.terminate()` sends `SIGTERM` to child then it is affected by it. This is probably the cause, not sure what your handler really does. But if for some reason it doesn't kill the child then then you are deadlocked.

Comment: It does kill the child. If you have a look at my handler `signal_term_handler()` There I check if its the parent pid or not. If its the parent I handle that in a way and if its the child I only do a `sys.exit(0)`. Have a look at the code I added in the edit (its a minimal version).

Comment: @edgarcosta The code you've shown us works as expected. There are two possibilities: either you did something funky in the signal handler **or** there's something in the child that blocks the signal, e.g. socket i/o.

Comment: Try to do multiple calls to `main()` using a for loop or something it gets stuck at p.join() if you call main() very fast. Note that at the beginning of main() I kill the previous process.

Comment: @edgarcosta I've just did that and it works as it should. I even tried both Python versions and still the same result. Also I don't see anything in the code that could go wrong. A little bit weird, indeed, but definitely correct.

Comment: Its linux and python 2.7? I tried in 3 computers right now and all of them fail.

Comment: @edgarcosta Yes, ubuntu 16.04. Maybe you should show us how exactly you run the code. I've just added `pt = ProcessTest()` and couple of `pt.main()` calls at the end.

Comment: Yes actually if I try it in your way it works (or it seems to work). Try with ipython please. I was doing ipython -i test.py and then `pt = ProcessTest()` and then `pt.main(); pt.main()`

Comment: @edgarcosta Right, got ya. I've finally managed to reproduce it. So it seems to be related to ipython (please update your question). I can't help you with that though, I assume some deep knowledge of ipython is needed here.

Comment: I am not that sure, because my original code its running with the normal interpreter `python code.py` and the same thing happens. I will say that is not related to `ipython`

Comment: @edgarcosta Well, to my knowledge the code should work fine with any Python version on any posix when called directly from `python`. Whatever the issue is, it is related to the signal handler. That's all I can do for you, good luck.

Comment: Actually now I made it fail with normal python interpreter. I started calling python example_code.py several times and at some point it hangs in the join(). Its something related to the `sys.exit(0)` I am almost sure, but I don't know what.

Comment: I think I know what is going on. sys.exit(0) raises an exception that if it is not cached it will exit the program. However, if something catches the exception   the program will not finish, from the tracebacks I was getting it seems to be the problem. So I have to find a replacement for sys.exti(0) that kills the process without raising the exception.

Comment: @freakish Can you have a look at my last update? I am almost sure I found the problem (actually there where 2 different ones, and I was in fact experiencing 2 different error traces). The first error is solved. But the second, its a race condition I am not sure how to solve it. I can not use a lock() in the handler function because it does an exit() so the lock will never be released. So what comes to my mind is a sleep(0.001).

Comment: @edgarcosta While you are right about 1) you actually **should** use `sys.exit()`. That's because otherwise you won't do the cleaning when leaving the process which can lead to some serious issues, including system-wide deadlocks (for example when you use fcntl). Just make sure you never do `except:` (or `except SystemExit:`) in your code and you'll be fine. You shouldn't do that anyway.

Comment: @edgarcosta As for 2). First of all signal handler does not run in a different thread. It runs in the main thread, the main code is simply interrupted. Secondly there is no race condition. You can call `p.join()` at any point and it will only unblock when the process quits. The state it is in at the moment of calling `p.join()` is irrelevant. So the order of `p.join()` and `sys.exit()` calls should be irrelevant.

Comment: @edgarcosta Anyway the classical (and proper) way to handle `SIGTERM` is to set a shared flag, for example `DURING_SHUTDOWN` and then let the main code act accordingly. Using `sys.exit()` in signal handler might have some weird side effect that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @freakish Well then the problem must be calling `p.start()` and `p.terminate()` just one right the other. Because what it is exactly happening is the following:
1) If there is no signal handler then upon calling `p.terminate()` the process finishes always and then the join does not get blocked.
2) However, if there is a handler for `SIGTERM`, in the case of calling `p.start()` and `p.terminate()` one after the other the process maybe very new or something but sometimes what is happening is that `terminate` does not do anything, so SIGTERM is not caught, and then join blocks.

Comment: If I add a `time.sleep(0.001)` before a `terminate()` it never hangs. So has to be related to the difference of time between you call start and terminate.